# Zend Framework Error handling

Tags: zend-framework

I would like to use the default ErrorCongtroller to handle error. I registered it as a front controller plugin and it does nothing. Should I set something else to catch not existing controllers and actions or should I add some code to other controllers?
Here's the code snippet for registration:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler());
$front->returnResponse(true);
$front->throwExceptions(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of ZF are you using? As far as I noticed in the latest versions, the error handler is registered by default. Only "thing" that it needs is an `ErrorController` in the default module with an `errorAction`

See the manual for details: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler

Comment: I use 1.9.5. I read that error controlle should be registered by default but it doesn't work. I use error controller from the Quickstart project (http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-your-project)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you set `$front->throwExceptions( false );`?

I believe the ErrorHandler only catches the Exceptions if you tell the front controller not to throw them (or, bubble them up, is what I mean I guess).

Also, are you doing anything with the returned response? Since you have set `$front->returnResponse( true );`, you need to collect the response yourself and output it with:

```
$response = $front->dispatch();
$response->sendResponse();
```

Comment: I already tried with both throwException true/false. There's no difference.